# Is there any way to recursively invoke a Rythm template based on some condition?

Tags: java, rythm

I'm currently using [Rythm](http://rythmengine.org) to create some snippets - in combination with [AST](http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fjdt%2Fcore%2Fdom%2FAST.html), as the templates depend on Java files.

[Invoking templates](http://rythmengine.org/doc/template_guide.md#invoke_template) works as expected. With one unexpected behaviour. I'd like to invoke a template recursively, but it seems this is not possible.

**Foo.html Template**

```
@args String someString, boolean recursion

Calling foo template with recursion: @recursion
@if(recursion) {
    A recursion was requested: @recursion
    @foo(someString, false)
}
```

**Note** this provides only 1 level of recursion, as per intention for this example. However, I'd like to use a condition instead of `false` within the `@foo(someString, false)` line later on.

You can try the snippet [here](http://fiddle.rythmengine.org/editor/#/editor/05fff88e36d24054807d6e5a5bc01477) by simply copying & pasting the provided example into `foo.html`.

**Error Message**

```
The method foo(String, boolean) is undefined for the type Cfoo_html__R_T_C__

Template: /foo.html

Relevant template source lines:
-------------------------------------------------
   1: @args String someString, boolean recursion
   2:     
   3:     Calling foo template with recursion: @recursion
   4:     @if(recursion) {
   5:       A recursion was requested: @recursion
>> 6:         @foo(someString, false)
   7:     }

/*
 * Omitted for the sake of readability.
 */
```

Now, the error seems not recursion related. Though, it is the error message I'm seeing in Eclipse.

I guess, when invoking a template it is not possible to invoke it within itself, because Rythm only looks for *other* templates - or so it seems.

Use the link above to access [*Rythm Fiddle*](http://fiddle.rythmengine.org/editor/#/editor/05fff88e36d24054807d6e5a5bc01477), put the code inside `bar.html` instead of `foo.html` - change line **#6** from `@foo(someString, false)` to `@bar(someString, false)`.

Now, put the following line inside of `foo.html`:

```
@bar("foo", true)
```

When doing so, the error changes to:

```
java.lang.SecurityException: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
```

I think this proves my assumption above, as Rythm now seems to find the template (or method, that is). And this is basically where I'm stuck.

So, the question is: *is there any way to recursively invoke a Rythm template based on some condition?*

I'm also open for other suggestions, as recursions usually can be handled in a non-recursive way. I just want to avoid duplicate code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rythm support `@this()` directive to load the template in a recursive way. See http://play-rythm-demo.appspot.com/demo/fibonacci

However it looks like there is a bug introduced and now it will raise `StackOverflowError` even when the terminate condition is specified. Please submit a bug report to https://github.com/rythmengine/rythmengine/issues

**Updates**

The `StackOverflowError` is caused by `boolean` type. It works all good if using other type of variable to control the termination of recursive call.

```
@args String foo, int i

<h1>@foo</h1>
Calling foo template with recursion: @i
@if(i > 1) {
A recursion was requested: @i
@this({foo: foo, recursion: false, i: (i - 1)})
}
```

Below is the test done on rythm fiddle

[image]

Comment: Perfect, that resolved the issue! I still do not find any documentation on that besides the example you sent. May I ask you to provide some documentation link as well?

Comment: Also, here is the issue I opened: [#363](https://github.com/rythmengine/rythmengine/issues/363).

Comment: @mcuenez unfortunately this feature is missed in the current documentation. Please submit an issue to rythm-doc project on github to track it

Comment: Now that explains why I can't find it. For a second, I thought I forgot how to google. Thanks for your help. Here's the rythm-doc issue: [#43](https://github.com/rythmengine/rythm-doc/issues/43).